# nvd3 linebar chart xAxis date format

Tags: jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a working line and bar chart but having problems getting the date to format appropriately on the xAxis. I did look around but couldn't find any linebar chart examples out there that used the same date format I need.

Here is what my json stored as variable looks like:

```
var data = [{
        "key": "Cases",
        "bar": true,
        "color": "skyblue",
        "values": [
            [2016-01-01, 13],
            [2016-01-02, 17],
            [2016-01-03, 19],
            [2016-01-04, 39],
            [2016-01-05, 46],
            [2016-01-06, 34],
            [2016-01-07, 36],
            [2016-01-08, 32]
        ]
    },

    {
        "key": "CSAT",
        "color": "steelblue",
        "values": [
            [2016-01-01, 9],
            [2016-01-02, 7],
            [2016-01-03, 10],
            [2016-01-04, 10],
            [2016-01-05, 8],
            [2016-01-06, 9],
            [2016-01-07, 10],
            [2016-01-08, 10]
        ]
    }
];
```

I believe this part of the code needs review:

```
    chart.xAxis.showMaxMin(true)
        .tickFormat(function (d) {
        var dx = data[0].values[d] && data[0].values[d][0] || 0;
        return d3.time.format('%Y-%d-%m')(new Date(dx));
    });
```

This code was originally written where the date is in epoch/unix format, however, my json has a different format for the date - it looks like this `2016-01-01 %Y-%d-%m`.

You can view the whole chart code here: http://jsfiddle.net/pty79q2z/

thanks in advance!

Comment: i have found the problem.. the dates in the json string need to be enclosed with double quotes

Comment: although the date is now displaying properly, i noticed i lost the tooltips.. when i mouse over the bar or lines there is no tooltip popup.. any ideas why? see latest fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/pty79q2z/2/

Comment: I noticed in my console i get this error when i mouseover the bars.. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined   VM11251:99`